# How can I build up a regex from component parts in Clojure?

Tags: regex, clojure

Regular expressions can be complicated, and I want to build them up as components instead as a single, gigantic regex string.  For example, if I want to match either a UUID, an SSN, or a phone number:

```
(let [uuid    "cafebabe-0867-5309-0666-0123456789ff"   
      ssn     "333-22-4444"
      phone   "619-239-5464"]
```

How can I combine the regex strings for the component parts into a single overall regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

We want to write each of our regex fragments as a Java String, using predefined character classes. However, this is inconvenient to write as a string literal since it will contain backslashes, each of which which must, in turn, be escaped by a backslash when written as a plain string.  This is even worse if our pattern itself must contain a backslash.

We can overcome this by using a placeholder character like the dollar sign `$` instead of using a backslash `\`.  After we finish building up the final string expression, we will substitute `$` => `\`, then construct a `java.util.regex.Pattern` object.

A solution in Clojure:

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.string :as str]))

;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
; regex "string" values with `$` as placeholder for backslash

(def uuid-regex-str
  "$p{XDigit}{8}       # 8 hex digits (posix char class)
   -                   # hyphen
   $p{XDigit}{4}       # 4 hex digits
   -                   # hyphen
   $p{XDigit}{4}       # 4 hex digits
   -                   # hyphen
   $p{XDigit}{4}       # 4 hex digits
   -                   # hyphen
   $p{XDigit}{12}      # 12 hex digits
   ")

(def phone-regex-str
  "$p{Digit}{3}   # 3 digits (posix char class)
   -              # hyphen
   $d{3}          # 3 digits (short form)
   -              # hyphen
   $p{Digit}{4}   # 4 digits
   ")

(def ssn-regex-str
 "$p{Digit}{3}   # 3 digits (posix char class)
  -              # hyphen
  $p{Digit}{2}   # 2 digits
  -              # hyphen
  $d{4}          # 4 digits (short form)
  ")
```

Then, combine the fragments into the final regex pattern:

```
(def uuid-phone-ssn-pattern
  (re-pattern
    (let [regex-str (str
                      "(?x)"  ; expanded form ignores whitespace & comments
                      uuid-regex-str
                      \|  ; or
                      phone-regex-str
                      \|  ; or
                      ssn-regex-str)]
      (str/replace regex-str \$ \\))))
```

with result

```
(dotest
  (let [uuid  "cafebabe-0867-5309-0666-0123456789ff"
        phone "619-239-5464" ; 619-239-KING
        ssn   "333-22-4444"]
    (is (re-matches uuid-phone-ssn-pattern uuid))
    (is (re-matches uuid-phone-ssn-pattern phone))
    (is (re-matches uuid-phone-ssn-pattern ssn))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shoehorn [spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec) into doing this. Otherwise, you may want to look into parsing libraries, such as [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse).

Spec is not specific for text parsing and lacks some of the conveniences of regices but you can build up your parser using components that you define with [spec/def](https://clojure.github.io/spec.alpha/clojure.spec.alpha-api.html#clojure.spec.alpha/def):

```
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as spec])

(defn flatten-seqs [dst src]
  (if (sequential? src)
    (reduce flatten-seqs dst src)
    (conj dst src)))

(defmacro cat-seq [& nested-seqs]
  (let [flat (flatten-seqs [] (eval `[~@nested-seqs]))]
    `(spec/cat ~@(interleave
                  (->> flat count range (map #(keyword (str "k" %))))
                  flat))))

(spec/def :demo/dec-digit (set (vec "0123456789")))
(spec/def :demo/hex-digit (set (vec "0123456789abcdef")))
(spec/def :demo/uuid (cat-seq (repeat 8 :demo/hex-digit)
                              #{\-}
                              (repeat 4 :demo/dec-digit)
                              #{\-}
                              (repeat 4 :demo/dec-digit)
                              #{\-}
                              (repeat 4 :demo/dec-digit)
                              #{\-}
                              (repeat 12 :demo/hex-digit)))
(spec/def :demo/ssn (cat-seq (repeat 3 :demo/dec-digit)
                              #{\-}
                             (repeat 2 :demo/dec-digit)
                              #{\-}
                             (repeat 4 :demo/dec-digit)))
(spec/def :demo/phone (cat-seq (repeat 3 :demo/dec-digit)
                               #{\-}
                               (repeat 3 :demo/dec-digit)
                               #{\-}
                               (repeat 4 :demo/dec-digit)))

(spec/def :demo/input (spec/alt :uuid :demo/uuid
                                :ssn :demo/ssn
                                :phone :demo/phone))
(spec/def :demo/inputs (spec/* :demo/input))
```

Here's how to use it:

```
(def uuid "cafebabe-0867-5309-0666-0123456789ff")
(def ssn "333-22-5464")
(def phone "123-555-6789")

(spec/valid? :demo/inputs (vec (str ssn phone)))
;; => true

(spec/valid? :demo/inputs (vec (str ssn phone "mjao")))
;; => false
```

Note that in case there are many different parsing alternatives, they get tagged with their type, e.g. `:ssn`, when using [conform](https://clojure.github.io/spec.alpha/clojure.spec.alpha-api.html#clojure.spec.alpha/conform):

```
(spec/conform :demo/inputs (vec (str ssn ssn)))
;; => [[:ssn {:k8 \4, :k5 \2, :k7 \5, :k9 \6, :k6 \-, :k0 \3, :k10 \4, :k3 \-, :k4 \2, :k1 \3, :k2 \3}] [:ssn {:k8 \4, :k5 \2, :k7 \5, :k9 \6, :k6 \-, :k0 \3, :k10 \4, :k3 \-, :k4 \2, :k1 \3, :k2 \3}]]
```